# Socket IO not receiving emit data after reconnect

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

may i know which part of the code that cause after the client disconnect and reconnect the chat message no longer show on the client browser, however the chat is still emit to server and other user will be able to see the message, just the original sender itself won't able to receive the message. I wonder it is socket issue or javascript issue?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

**Socket IO Version 1.3.7**

**Notes: I am integrating the chat with laravel so will not use any nodejs routing here, i guess it wont cause any problem for me right since the chat is able to function normally...just the problem above i currently facing now**

```
//server.js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    //console.log('a user connected: ' + socket.id);
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log( socket.name + ' has disconnected from the chat.' + socket.id);
        io.emit('user', io.sockets.sockets.length);
        io.emit('chat message', socket.name + ' has disconnected from the chat.');
    });
    socket.on('join', function (name) {
        socket.name = name;
        console.log(socket.name + ' joined the chat.'+ socket.id);
        io.emit('user', io.sockets.sockets.length);
        io.emit('chat message', socket.name + ' joined the chat.');
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
        console.log(msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

''

```
//Client code here
<div class="board" style="position: absolute;right:40%;width:350px;height:500px;" id="liveQuickAskDesk">

        <h2 class="timberGradient">Live Quick Ask Desk</h2>
        <div id="innerQuickAskDesk">
            <span id="total_user"></span> staff online currently
            <button type="button" id="disconnect" class="btn btn-danger">Offline</button>
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="messagewindow" style="position: absolute;height:330px;overflow: auto;">
                <span id="messages"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form style="position: absolute;margin:110% 0 0 0;width:320px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Message:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="m">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-12 center-block" id="connect_div">
            <button type="button" id="connect" class="btn btn-primary center-block" style="margin-top: 50%;">Online</button>
        </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>

      $("#connect_div").hide();
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
      var name = "<?php echo $user_name ?>";

      $('#disconnect').click(function(){
          socket.disconnect();
          $("#liveQuickAskDesk").css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)');
          $("#innerQuickAskDesk").hide();
          $("#connect_div").show();
          $('#messages').html("");
      });
      $('#connect').click(function(){
          socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000',{'forceNew':true});
          socket.on('connect', function(msg){
              socket.emit('join', name);
              console.log("client reconnect to the server");
          });
          $("#liveQuickAskDesk").css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
          $("#connect_div").hide();
          $("#innerQuickAskDesk").show();

      });

      socket.on('connect', function(msg){
          socket.emit('join', name);
          console.log("client join the server");
      });
      socket.on("disconnect", function(){
          console.log("client disconnected from server");
      });

      $('form').submit(function(){
      $('#messagewindow').animate({ scrollTop:$('#messagewindow').prop('scrollHeight')}, 10);
        socket.emit('chat message', "Staff "+name+": "+$('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });

      socket.on('user', function(msg){
        $('#total_user').html(msg);
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<p>').text(msg));
      });

    </script>

</div>
```

Comment: Messages are not stored anywhere, are they ?

Comment: Yea message are not stored anywhere, just normal send and receive client->server->client

Comment: You will need a DB for that. You could have global variables to store user messages too..

Comment: Yea in future i will add a DB, but i wonder is it possible for the problem to be solve without a DB now? Cause for now not really need to store anything but just let the new message append after reconnect will do~

Comment: Do you want to keep the state of the last messages after reconnect ? If yes, then that is not possible using your approach..After reconnect user will be able to send and receive messages..I suppose..

Comment: Nope i don't want any old message, i just want to send and receive the new message from other user or myself after reconnect. For now after reconnect the user can send message but will not able to receive any message (either by myself or other user...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are losing your listeners when disconnect and reconnect, so keeping your listeners inside a function and calling it each time you connect should be ok.

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000',{'forceNew':true});
setevts();

 function setevts () {

   socket.on('connect', function(msg){
      socket.emit('join', name);
      console.log("client join the server");
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", function(){
      console.log("client disconnected from server");
  });

   socket.on('user', function(msg){
    $('#total_user').html(msg);
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<p>').text(msg));
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following code on server side to fix this same issue

```
let socketServer = new socketIOServer(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

socketServer.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socketServer.to(socket.id).emit("event", "msg");
});
```